# Windows - Unknown File Type & Windows Web "Lookup"

Tags: windows, web-services, file-extension

On MS Windows, when you double-click a file with an unknown file extension, the OS presents you with a message giving you a a choice of:

**1 - Use the Web service to find the appropriate program**

**2 - Select the program from a list**

Is there a way to "register" your file extension with MS (or whoever) to allow your application to show as a result when the "Use the Web service to find the appropriate program" is selected?

Comment: How is that programming related? The best possible answer probably is "write them and see if they do anything".

Comment: "How is that programming related?" How would it NOT be programming related? I cannot think of any other profession/job that would need an answer to this question. It is a concern to me... as a programmer, related to a program I am working on.

Comment: Maybe I am too strict, but I see it as "Is about programming" / "Has a solution that involves programming". This question is failing both tests.

Comment: This "is about programming". IMHO.